Horror movie with children lurking behind a mirror. Pregnant woman tries to uncover their secret
I have a vague remembrance of this movie. From what I can remember, a woman, who I believe is pregnant, sees children lurking beyond a mirror in a large bathroom. She goes through the, now broken, mirror into a gritty room filled with dirty rustic chairs. She then enters a small hand cranked elevator. Going down, she then arrives in a clean white corridor, where weird beings later appear to be walking towards her.
The language of the movie was either English or Spanish. The genre was probably horror, mystery. I saw it about eight years ago.

Yes, it was House of voices. Thank you Richard.
